# Error 500 (Internal Server Error) After Clearing Cache

Tags: caching

I truncated **cache_block** and **cache_bootstrap** tables in Drupal database (I don't know if its okay to truncate cache tables) and after that my site went down.

I am getting **HTTP Error 500** that says

> The website encountered an error
>   while retrieving www.drupalwebsite.com. It may be down for maintenance
>   or configured incorrectly.

Before truncating those tables, my site was working fine. Is there any way to get it back to working??

---

> UPDATE -

***I cleared all other cache tables too...***

***WEBSERVER LOGS -***

> [Thu Dec 27 02:51:24 2012] [warn] [client *IP_Address*] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctools_include() in /var/www/vhosts/*my_site_name*/drupal/sites/all/modules/views/views.module on line 62

Comment: Can you check your PHP error log, Drupal dblog (if you have drush) and report back with what you see.

Comment: You need to read your webserver logs to find out what is causing the error.

Comment: Try truncating other cache tables too.

Comment: Is your Ctools module folder exist?

Comment: @kalabro yes it does, but the module is disabled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somehow your site has entered a broken state since the Views module depends on ctools but it's not enabled.

What you need to do to fix it is to:

1. Enable the ctools module in the database, by running the following SQL `UPDATE system SET status = 1 WHERE name = 'ctools';`
2. Truncate all the cache tables in your database.
3. (Might not be needed) run `$ drush rr`, requires drush and the registry rebuild extension.
4. Run `$ drush cc all` requires drush.

Going through the above list should fix your site. Messing with your sites cache table can be a bit dangerous if you don't know what you are doing since drupal caches what modules it needs to load for performance.

You can read more about and download [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) and [registry rebuild](http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) on drupal.org.

Comment: Thanks so much.. I followed the first two steps and site is running now.. I know now I dont have to, but am just a little curious, how and where do I run - $ drush rr. Sorry but I am new to Drupal

Comment: Drush is a shell extension for drupal, that allows you to be able to do stuff on your Drupal site from the shell.

Comment: @see http://drupal.org/project/drush

Answer (score 0):

I found this tool extremely useful in resoling similar problems. Just on your server, wget boomshadow.net/tools-utils/fixperms.sh
Then, sh ./fixperms.sh -a USER-NAME